# Why aren't lists hashable and how do I get around them

Tags: python, list, dictionary, hash

I am trying to get a premade dict, save some user inputs into a list and later print out what they user has inputted in. Although I know how to do that part, I want to format the saved user inputs and change their names around by the dictionary Here is my code

```
print("Hi There! Welcome to sSpecialists!")
print("To start shopping, note down what you want to buy and how much of it")
print("Here are the purchasable items")
print("~~~~~")
print("12345670 is a hammer (£4.50)")
print("87654325 is a screw driver (£4.20)")
print("96385272 is a pack of 5 iron screws (£1.20)")
print("74185290 is pack of 20 100mm bolts (£1.99)")
print("85296374 is a pack of 6 walkers crisps (£1)")
print("85274198 is haribo pack (£1)")
print("78945616 is milk (£0.88)")
print("13246570 is a bottle of evian water (£0.99)")
print("31264570 is kitkat original (£0.50)")
print("91537843 is a cadbury bar (£1)")
print("~~~~~")
items = {'12345670' : {'name' : 'hammer', 'price' : 4.50},
         '87654325' : {'name' : 'screwDriver', 'price' : 4.20},
         '96385272' : {'name' : 'packOf5IronnScrews', 'price' : 1.20},
         '74185290' : {'name' : 'packOf200mmBolts', 'price' : 1.99},
         '85296374' : {'name' : 'packOf6WalkersCrisps', 'price' : 1},
         '85274198' : {'name' : 'hariboPack', 'price' : 1},
         '78945616' : {'name' : 'milk', 'price' : 0.88},
         '13246570' : {'name' : 'bottleOfEvianWater', 'price' : 0.99},
         '31264570' : {'name' : 'kitkatOriginal', 'price' : 0.50},
         '91537843' : {'name' : 'cadburyBar', 'price' : 1}}
print("Alright, now start typing what you want to order")
print(" ")
price = 0
full_list = " "
chos_items = []
while full_list != "":
    print(" ")
    full_list = input("Type: ")
    if full_list == 'end':
        break
    item = int(full_list)
    amount = int(input("Amount: "))
    item = int(full_list)
    if full_list in items:
        orders = print("{}    {:>5}    (£{:0.2f})".format(full_list, items[full_list]['name'], items[full_list]['price']))
        if orders != "":
            chos_items.append(full_list)
        price  = int(amount) * (items[full_list]['price']) + price
        print("Subtotal is currently at "+str(price))
print("Your subtotal is: " +str(price))
receipt = input("Would you like to view your receipt?: ")
if receipt == 'yes':
    for item in items:
        print(print("{}    {:>5}    (£{:0.2f})".format(chos_items,         items[chos_items]['name'], items[chos_items]['price'])))
```

Comment: No this is different because I need to append to a list

Comment: Why would you want to use a list as a key??

Comment: What does that mean? Sorry I'm doing this for my gcses and I'm in high school

Comment: Wait, do you even understand what that code does? Why are you trying to use a list as a key when your dict uses integers for the keys?

Comment: I am trying to format a user input, but I want to format all of what the user has inputted in, this can mean that the user has inputted in multiple things which are later stored in a list. The problem is you can't hash lists

Comment: And yes, I do know what this code does, I made it all myself

Comment: In that case you should know why `items[chos_items]['name'], items[chos_items]['price']` is wrong and won't work...

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm trying to fix but, I want to save ALL of the user's inputs and then hash that

Comment: You cannot hash mutable types. I don't know why you are trying to do that. Just iterate over `chos_items` and use the elements of this list to access the corresponding values in the dict. Or implement your own dict-like class that somehow handles this

Comment: Ok thanks but I don't know how to do that. Care to explain, if not tell me what to research.